# Smartface iOS Emulator Fails to Start

Tags: smartface.io

No matter what I try, I seem to get this message every time I click the Device Emulator button. I have an iPad Air 2 connected to my PC with Smartface in action installed.

"Keep calm ;) 
You need to download Smartface in action from app store and then please try again.

Same issue again? Please refer to Troubleshooting document!"

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the new restrictions in iOS 8.3.

You can download the emulator project from the link below :
https://github.com/smartface/iOS-Emulator

After that you can compile your own emulator and use it.

Comment: This presumes I have a Mac. I don't. This was my original attraction to SmartFace. Any idea if and when this will be resolved? Or is it something that cannot be resolved without me buying a Mac and building the emulator myself?

Comment: Yes, this is the case for community users, you need a Mac. But there is an option for licenced users. If you get a licence, the emulator will be shared with you. Please check the link about licence : https://account.smartface.io/License/ Also there are other and faster supports for licenced users about their problems that they could face.

Comment: Are you saying this issue will only be fixed for paying customers?

Comment: With the next release, iOS emulator will be used by licenced users only. But Android emulator will be free and can be used by all of the users including community users.

Comment: Some documentation about this limitation on the web site would be helpful.